# How to bundle a static YAML file with a React Native app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native

I'd like to ship my React Native app together with some static assets, like images, audio files, and one YAML file.

The images can be automatically bundled as [described here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images):

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

Now I'm trying to do the same with the YAML file. This seems to work:

```
let yamlContent = require('../data/content.yaml');
```

However, when running this in the Android simulator, I get an error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../content.yaml` from 
`C:\Users\....\path\to\loader.ts`: 
The module `../content.yaml` could not be found from 
`C:\Users\....\path\to\loader.ts`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `C:\Users\....\path\to\data\content.yaml(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `C:\Users\....\path\to\content.yaml\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
```

I double-checked the path in the output, the file really exists.

**How can I read static YAML files in React Native?**

I also tried the same code outside of React Native, in a Node.js console app. In this situation, the file seems to be read (if the YAML is malformed, I get an error). However, the object `yamlContent` is always an empty Javascript object.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Zennichimaro Not really. We're converting the yaml files to json and then bundle the json files.

Comment: I've been finding a lot of information updating the webpack.config.js file but in involves ejecting the react app first: https://github.com/joepagan/js-yaml-loader-test

Answer (score -1):

Close 'packager' and delete **node_modules** folder.

and than reinstall all packages with **npm install** command

Comment: Tried that, but same problem. If I try a `content.json` instead of a `content.yaml`, everything works fine.